# How can I show the syntax-colored current line wrapped on top of current line in nowrap buffer?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wrapping, popup

I know this can look a lot like a duplicate of [Vim wrap only current line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8685/vim-wrap-only-current-line), but none of the answers give a real solution to the original problem, as all of them state that per-line soft wrapping is not possible, proposing alternatives like hard wrapping the line and undoing the change afterwards, or showing the wrapped line in an ad-hoc buffer.

Furthermore, 6 years have passed, Vim has improved, and I wonder if new solutions exist.

A strategy that looks promising to me is to have an `autocmd CursorHold` showing a popup populated by the current line only, with horizontal scrolling taking into account stuff I use all the time, like `number`, `relativenumber`, `list lcs`.

Leaving aside for now the `autocmd`/`augroup` part of the strategy, what I've come up with is the following,

```
function! Foo()
  call popup_create(getline('.'),
    \ #{ line: 'cursor', col: screencol() - virtcol('.') + 1, moved: [line('.'), 0, col('$')], })
endfunction
```

which does a pretty good job in terms of formatting,
[image]

Except that the line is not syntax-colored (the `3` would have to be the same color as the other digits a few lines above).

I've found out that the first argument to `popup_create` can be a buffer number, which means that popup will be populated with that buffer. This seems useful, but I haven't been able to use it to show only the current line. I *can start from the current line*, via `firstline` option, but don't know how to set a final line, as `lastline` doesn't do the job¹ (probably I don't understand what it is for). Here's the second attempt I'm referring to:

```
function! Foo()
  call popup_setoptions(
    \ popup_create(
    \   bufnr('.'),
    \   #{ line: 'cursor', col: screencol() - virtcol('.') + 1, moved: [line('.'), 0, col('$')], }
    \ ),
    \ #{ wrap: 1, firstline: line('.')})
endfunction
```

and here's the result
[image]

Well, there's also the problem of the background of the popup, but that's likely easier to fix.

---

(¹) In the sense that I get the same output as the one in second screenshot, whther or not I put `lastline: line('.') + 1` or `lastline: line('.')` in in `popup_setoptions`'s second argument.

Comment: What happens if use `lastline: line('.') + 1`? Also test without +1. Adding info to the question helps.

Comment: I've clarified what I meant by _doesn't to the job_. I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trick was to use `maxheight` and compute it based on how much text is on the current line and how much space is in the terminal width.

With the following solution

```
function! Foo()
  let available_screen = &columns - max([0, screencol() - virtcol('.')])
  call popup_setoptions(
    \ popup_create(
    \   bufnr(),
    \   #{ line: 'cursor', col: screencol() - virtcol('.') + 1, moved: [line('.'), 0, col('$')], }
    \ ),
    \ #{
    \    wrap: 1,
    \    firstline: line('.'),
    \    maxheight: float2nr(ceil(len(getline(line('.')))*1.0/available_screen)),
    \    scrollbar: 0
    \  })
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>sb :call Foo()<cr>
```

(and temporarily changing `moved` to `[0, 0, 0]` to make popups permanent), I obtained this result:
[image]
For reference, this is without the popups:
[image]

Clearly, when hitting the left border of the terminal, the popup has to stop moving left and so it is not aligned with the underlying text, but I think this can't be avoided (unless manually wrapping words back on previous lines).

Comment: If/when you finish the code for wrapped lines, I'll be curious to see it

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, so you're not referring to the solution in the first screenshot in this answer. Maybe you're referring to something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQCfY.jpg)? If so, then that's a variation of this which requires little change to the code. Both variations are in review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/281615/show-entire-current-line-in-popup-over-current-line-in-no-wrap-text).

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear: I meant if you wrap this up in a script or plugin I'd be curious to look at it or try it

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, still, you just need to copy the code from [there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/281615/show-entire-current-line-in-popup-over-current-line-in-no-wrap-text), put it in your vimrc, load, and let the cursor on some non-totally-visible line. I could put the two variants of the solution under an option and make a plugin... Why not.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, [here it is](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap). Please, feel free to give some feedback. You can set `g:softwrap_unwrap` to `v:false` (default) or `v:true` in your vimrc to keep the popup in the current window or let it overflow. That's the only customization point at the moment.